# Javascript convert a true/false value string text

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a jQuery script that collects the values of checkboxes in variables:

```
var 1_val = $("input[type='checkbox'][name='val_1']").prop( "checked" );
var 2_val = $("input[type='checkbox'][name='val_2']").prop( "checked" );
```

Then I output these in a message to be sent via e-mail:

```
...<strong>Value 1</strong>: 1_val + '<br /><strong>Value 2</strong>: ' + 2_val + '<br />...
```

But in the message body I get the string with booleans true/false, and I would want to make some more user-friendly message like Yes/No. How can I change it?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Assign that value to the variable:

```
var 1_val = $("input[type='checkbox'][name='val_1']").prop( "checked" ) ? "Yes" : "No";
```

Comment: This works well if these variables are only used for output, but will break things if they are being used in boolean form elsewhere in the code

Answer (score 1):

You can use the ternary operator (which is essentially a short if-statement):

```
(2_val ? 'Yes' : 'No')
```

The value of this expression will be the string `Yes` if `2_val == true`, else `No`.

Answer (score 1):

You could replace `1_val` with `(1_val ? 'Yes' : 'No')` when you output it. (and do the same for `2_val`) Alternatively, if you only use these variables for this output, you could do what tymeJV suggests.

Answer (score 1):

Probably far from being the best solution, but one way would be:

```
var YesNo = {
   'true' : 'Yes',
   'false' : 'No'
};
```

And use like this on your HTML fragment:

```
var html = '<strong>Value 1 :</strong>' 
    + YesNo[val_1] + '<strong>Value 2</strong>' + YesNo[val_2];
```